Excel, sort by row
Is there a way to sort by row in an Excel spreadsheet? For example, if I have something like this...

How can I sort, alphabetically, by rows, so it would look like this...

Thanks in advance.

Your example sorts every column seperately, is that what you meant to ask?

Try this once: =TRANSPOSE(WRAPCOLS(SORT(TOCOL(A2:J11)),10))

My two cents:

=LET(r,A2:J11,MAP(r,LAMBDA(s,INDEX(SORT(INDEX(r,0,COLUMN(s))),ROW(s)-1))))


Use REDUCE and HSTACK:
=LET(rng,A2:J21,DROP(REDUCE("",COLUMN(rng)-MIN(COLUMN(rng))+1,LAMBDA(z,y,HSTACK(z,SORT(INDEX(rng,0,y))))),,1))



Here is few other ways:


=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A2:J11)),LAMBDA(α,δ,HSTACK(α,SORT(INDEX(A2:J11,0,δ))))),,1)


Or, May be this one:
=TRANSPOSE(WRAPCOLS(SORT(TOCOL(A2:J11)),10))



One caveat to the second one is, that works if the columns all contain the same data like the op test data.  But if the test data is not uniform then the data will switch columns.  Which again may be okay.

@ScottCraner Sir, agree that is why I have not prioritized the second in the top.

This should do it:
=MAKEARRAY(10, 10, LAMBDA(r, c, CHOOSEROWS(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A2:J11, c)), r)))

or
=WRAPROWS(SORT(TOCOL(A2:J11)),10)



Sort Each Column
REDUCE/HSTACK

More of the same, except:

included headers,
got rid of DROP (Is it worth the complication? Probably not!).



=LET(data,A1:J11,
    d,DROP(data,1),
    VSTACK(TAKE(data,1),REDUCE(SORT(TAKE(d,,1)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(d)-1,,2),LAMBDA(rr,c,
        HSTACK(rr,SORT(CHOOSECOLS(d,c)))))))

Edit

The issue with the above DROPless REDUCE version is that it doesn't work for a single column. Therefore I would opt for the following:

=LET(data,A1:J11,
    d,DROP(data;1),
    VSTACK(TAKE(data,1),DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(d)),LAMBDA(rr,c,
        HSTACK(rr,SORT(CHOOSECOLS(d,c))))),,1)))


